# Convert JSON to CSV

Tags: json, csv

I'm working on storing around 200 000 Json objects into a CSV file. But the problem is that any 2 JSON Objects might be different (having different key names).

I thought about creating a HashSet and traverse through all objects once so as to get column names for my CSV file. But this process is apparently taking too much time.

Is there another way to add columns to a CSV file dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `jq` ("Json Query"):

```
def tocsv:
  if length == 0 then empty
  else
    (.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys
    | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $allkeys
    | ($keys + ($allkeys - $keys)) as $cols
    | ($cols, (.[] as $row | $cols | map($row[.])))
    | @csv
  end ;

tocsv
```

For example, assuming the above is in a file named json2csv.jq and that the input is in in.json:

```
jq -r -f json2csv.jq in.json
```

The above program constructs the header line by starting with the key names of the first object (in the order in which they appear there), and then extends the header line as required.

For more about jq, see https://stedolan.github.io/jq

Another approach would be to use `in2csv`, part of the csvkit tookit -- see https://csvkit.readthedocs.org